# Clojure printing while the script is still running to the REPL

Tags: clojure

How do you print your output into REPL whilst the script is still running? I've notice that it stores everything to buffer, and then prints once it completes the code.

```
(defn -main
  [x]
  (when (pos? x)
    (println x)
    (Thread/sleep 10000)
    (recur (dec x))))
(-main 10)
```

Comment: I think you need to [`flush`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flush).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java (& thus Clojure) use buffered output. If you are trying to print in the middle of a tight loop, you need the `flush`:

```
(println x)
(flush)
```

Comment: Thanks this was right, I had used this before but I tried to load the file into the REPL and it didn't spit out the outputs in real time.